# Giving struct to function with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, scanf

In C I'm trying to use a struct to store the current data of the player, which I manage in a struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct playerdat{
  char playername[20];
  int maxhp;
}playerdat;

void new_game(struct playerdat *player){

  printf("Enter your character's name: \n");
  scanf("%s", &player->playername);
  player->playername = strcpy("Little", player->playername);
}

int main(){

  struct playerdat player;
  new_game(&player);

  return 0;
}
```

Everything is working correctly, until I try to change the elements of the struct.

The error message reads as: **error: incompativle types when assignin to type 'char[20]' from type 'char *'**

Can you please show me an example of how the pointers should be used here?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not "off-topic". It should just be ` scanf("%s", player->playername);` rather than `scanf("%s", &player->playername);`. `scanf` wants a `char*`, and `player->playername` already is a `char*`, you must not make a reference to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("%s", &player->playername);//don't need &
player->playername = strcpy("Little", player->playername);//you know,the memeber `playername` is a array,`playername` is the name of the array,so you can't modify the name of a array
```

Comment: Then how do I change the contents of the player.playername character array?

Comment: like this:
`char *name = "Little"`;

`strncpy(player->playername,name ,strlen(name)+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use & with char on scanf.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        char name[20];
        int age;
        printf ("Enter your family name: ");
        scanf ("%s",name); //notice here no &
        printf ("Enter your age: ");
        scanf ("%d",&age);  // here comes &
        return 0;
    }
```